# linq - fill out sparse table for plot

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with an event id pk, date column and an event type column.
I want to use linq to get the count of events in each day.
The issue is that the table is sparse, i.e. values are not stored in days which did not have any events.

Since I want to use this data for a line chart, I need to fill out the data with the missing dates and give them a value of zero.

Is these any way to do this inside linq? or do I have to do this manually?

Is there any recommended method of doing this?

**Edit:**

I created the following method:

```
public string GetDailyData(int month, int year)
    {
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month);
        DateTime firstOfTheMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
        PaymentModelDataContext db = new PaymentModelDataContext();
        var q = from daynumber in Enumerable.Range(0, days)
                let day = firstOfTheMonth.AddDays(daynumber)
                join data in db.TrackingEvents on day equals data.timestamp.Day into d2
                from x in d2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Value);

        return ParseJson(q);
    }
```

The problem is I get an error on the 'join' keyword:
"The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'"

**Edit 2:**
I made the changes suggested and tried to group the results.
When I send them to the parsing function, I get a null object ref error.
Here is the new code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetDailyData(int month, int year)
    {
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        DateTime firstOfTheMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
        PaymentModelDataContext db = new PaymentModelDataContext();
        var q = from daynumber in Enumerable.Range(0, days)
                let day = firstOfTheMonth.AddDays(daynumber)
                join data in db.TrackingEvents on day equals data.timestamp.Date into d2
                from x in d2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group x by x.timestamp.Date;

        return ParseJson(q);
    }
```

And the parsing function:

```
private string ParseJson<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> q)
    {
        string returnJSON = "[{ \"type\" : \"pie\", \"name\" : \"Campaigns\", \"data\" : [ ";
        foreach (var grp in q)
        {
            double currCount = grp.Count();
            if (grp.Key != null)
                returnJSON += "['" + grp.Key + "', " + currCount + "],";
            else
                returnJSON += "['none', " + currCount + "],";
        }
        returnJSON = returnJSON.Substring(0, returnJSON.Length - 1);
        returnJSON += "]}]";

        return returnJSON;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use LINQ.  One method is to use Enumerable.Range to create a collection of dates between the min and max dates, and then perform an outer join (using GroupJoin) against the sparse table. (See [MSDN Reference: How to Perform Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx))

For instance, if `numdays` is the date range (in days), `MinDate` is the initial date, and `SparseData` is your sparse data, and `SparseData` has an instance property `Day` that specifies the date, then you might do:

```
var q = Enumerable.Range(0, numdays)
        .Select(a => MinDate.AddDays(a))
        .GroupJoin(
           SparseData,
           q=>q,
           sd=>sd.Day,
           (key, value) =>
               Tuple.Create(
                     key,
                     value.DefaultIfEmpty().First()
               )
          );
```

Or, equivalently,

```
  var q2 = from daynumber in Enumerable.Range(0, numdays)
           let day = MinDate.AddDays(daynumber)
           join data in SparseData on day equals data.Day into d2
           from x in d2.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Value);
```

Comment: I updated my post with code I wrote using your answer. I am still having some issues. Thanks!

Comment: Is your PaymentModelDataContext.timestamp of type DateTime?  If so, you may need to change "data.timestamp.Day" to "data.timestamp.Date".  A common type needs to be inferred for both sides of the `equals` clause, and this error will occur if the compiler is unable to infer a common type.  ([some more information is here in the accepted response](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/bf98ec7a-cb80-4901-8eb2-3aa6636a4fde/).)

Comment: Thank you again. One last thing. I want to group the events by timestamp.Date. I tried adding 'group x by x.timestamp.date', but that didn't work.

Comment: There are a number of ways, but if each record in db.TrackingEvents is an event, then you could do something like `from events in db.TrackingEvents group events by events.timestamp.Date into groupedevents select new {Date=groupedevents.Key, EventCount=groupedevents.Count()}`.  (This table would still be sparse, but you could use an outer join to populate with the missing dates.)

Answer (score 2):

The code I've written follows an almost identical approach to that suggested in @drf's answer - outer joining the aggregated results to the complete set of dates.
However, it's slightly simpler and I believe it produces the output format you want (also, I've compiled and run it, so it at least does what *I* expect it to :-))

I've assumed a collection called `events`, the members of which have a property `timestamp`
Note that I've assumed the timestamps may include times as well as dates - if this isn't the case you can simplify the code slightly by omitting the `.Date`s

Finally, I've determined the range of dates to be defined by the period you have data for - obviously you can change the `startDate` and `endDate` values

```
DateTime startDate = events.OrderBy(e=>e.timestamp).First().timestamp.Date;
DateTime endDate = events.OrderBy(e=>e.timestamp).Last().timestamp.Date;
var allDates = Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate - startDate).Days + 1)      
                        .Select(a => startDate.AddDays(a))
                        .GroupJoin(events, d=>d.Date, e=>e.timestamp,  
                            (d, e) => 
                                new{date = d, count = e.Count()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in LINQ2SQL as far as I can figure out, but the standard trick when you write a stored procedure is to generate a list of all dates in the range, filter out those already in the list and take a union of the results.

This should be quite easy to do in LINQ2Objects once you have retrieved the sparse data.